# Django displaying uploaded images

Tags: django, django-templates

I am working on an application that allows users to upload PDFs. I want to display the PDFs in various templates.

I am using multi-tenant so that may be an issue. So far, I haven't been able to get the PDFs to display. In the place of the image I see:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://co1.localhost:8000/projects/project/1/document/2/projects/documents/012022/Joint1021S.pdf
```

The view:

```
class ProjectDocumentsCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ProjectDocuments
    template_name = 'company_accounts/add_project_document.html'
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'file']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        project = get_object_or_404(Project, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        document = form.save(commit=False)
        document.project = project
        document.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('project_detail', args=[self.kwargs.get('pk')])

class ProjectDocumentsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = ProjectDocuments
    id = ProjectDocuments.objects.only('id')
    template_name = 'company_accounts/project_document_detail.html'
```

The template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="section-container container">
  <div class="project-entry">
    <h2>{{ projectdocuments.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ projectdocuments.description | safe }}</p>
    <embed src="{{ projectdocuments.file }}"
    <img src="{{ projectdocuments.file }}">

    <p>{{ projectdocuments.file }}</p>
  </div>
  <div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

In the main site config/urls I have the line:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Media settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Model:

```
class ProjectDocuments(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    description = models.TextField()
    file = ConstrainedFileField(
                            null=True,
                            blank=True,
                            upload_to='projects/documents/%m%Y',
                            content_types=['application/pdf'],
                            max_upload_size=2097152,
                                    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, default=0, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_documents')
```

The files (in this specific instance) are stored in a file in media>company1>documents>012022>file.pdf

From the error, at least one issue appears to be the way the path to the pdf is being constructed. Any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the full view (including the context at least) as well as your media url settings. Also the model with the upload field. View would be helpful to see what object you did set as context (maybe urls got changed here) and the model and settings as they usually set the URL of the uploaded file together.

Comment: I added the media settings and the model. That actually is my full view. I am new to Django so that may be at least part of the problem.

Comment: settings and model look alright so far; I guess the issue might be in the view. Last half of the url django tries to call when throwing 404 matches what you defined in the upload field. So it would be great if you could provide the full view function.

Comment: I added the create view class to the model section above.

Comment: I just figured out it works if I add ".url" to the file template tag ex: ```<embed src="{{ projectdocuments.file.url }}```